# problems with using regexner to override existing named entities while maintaining entitymentions

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am using Stanford CoreNLP 3.9.1 on a Mac running Java version 1.8.0_101. I have CoreNLP running and have been able to leverage most of the annotators. I am trying to fine-tune my named entity recognition and having problems over-riding existing mappings.

Below is the content of properties file:
    # This file is launched with the following command:
    # Marks-MacBook-Pro-4:stanford-corenlp-full-2018-02-27 moranmarkd$ java -cp "*" -Xmx8g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -props ner-3.props

```
annotators = tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner

# RegexNER mappings file - this is different than just the regexner file...this should incorporate with Named Entity Mentions
ner.additional.regexner.mapping = regexner-1.txt

# Where to find the list of input files
filelist = CL-Cleaned-Infiles.txt

# Where to place and how to format output
outputDirectory = ../../CL-Cleaned-CoreNLP-ner3-json
outputFormat = json
```

Below is the content of regexner-1.txt
    John Deere\tORGANIZATION\tPERSON\n
    New Holland\tORGANIZATION\tCOUNTRY\n

I have tried using both the regexner annotator at the end of the pipeline and invoking additional mapping (as above) and not able to override the defaults identification of John Deere as a person and New Holland as a country.

I have also tried invoking all of these same settings from a long command line with no success either:
    java -cp "*" -Xmx8g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -anotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner -ner.additional.regexner.mapping regexner-1.txt -filelist CL-Cleaned-Infiles.txt -outputDirector ../../CL-Cleaaned-CoreNLP-ner3-json -outputFormat json

My preference was to do the additional mapping instead of regexner to be able to still impact Entity Mentions (as I understand the pipeline).

Any advice on how to troubleshoot, what to correct, or what to try is welcome.

Best,

Mark

Comment: This may help: in my case, I was getting CoreNLP NER tags or RegexNER, not both ("blended" tags).  It was due to missing #CLASSPATH and models; once I added those and correctly called the annotators ... everything worked! Comments here: https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/issues/983#issuecomment-573536392

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the current documentation matches the current code available on GitHub, so Stanford CoreNLP 3.9.1 doesn't have the refined ner pipeline (which was just added a couple weeks ago).  I'll make a note of this on the page.

We are working to get Stanford CoreNLP 3.9.2 out fairly soon (matter of weeks).

It's very straight forward to create a jar with the code from GitHub.  The instructions are on the main page.

If you have any other questions please let me know.

https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP

I ran this command on your example with your rules and got the proper results (using the latest code):

```
java -Xmx10g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner -ner.additional.regexner.mapping override_example.rules -file override_example.txt -outputFormat text
```